# I can not get Visual Studio to recognize my Python Package for an integrated languages assignment

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I am doing a C++and Python integration assignment, but I can not get Visual Studio to properly locate the external Python files. I placed the include and libs paths for Python in the general tab in my project configuration and in the VC++ tab as well. These are the errors I get.

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ModuleSixAssignment, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyImport_ImportModule
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_BuildValue
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Finalize
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_Dealloc
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Initialize
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_GetDict
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_GetAttrString
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyDict_GetItemString
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_CallObject
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyImport_Import
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyCallable_Check
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyLong_AsInt
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Print
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyUnicode_FromString
1>C:\Users\alhim\OneDrive\Documents\VisualStudio\ModuleSixAssignment\Release\ModuleSixAssignment.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 14 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "ModuleSixAssignment.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you add the Python library to the list of libraries you need?  It should be `python38.lib`

Comment: I added the libs folder which includes that specific file

Comment: Yes, but you also have to tell it the name of the library itself.  It will search through the folders to find it, but it has to know what it's looking for.

Comment: How do I do that there is only an option to add the path but not a specific file

Comment: Under Linker -> Input in Additional Dependencies.  Or, add `#pragma comment(lib, "python38.lib")` in the code.

Comment: i tried both methods still all the same errors

Comment: Are you running Python 3.8?  I'm not sure where I got that from your question.  If you look in the library directory, do you see a Python library?

Comment: I got the latest python package it's 3.9 but I made sure I put 3.9 in the linker and the pragma line but it didn't find it